# pyFFTW installation -> cannot find -lfftw3_threads

Tags: python, pyfftw

I am trying to install pyFFTW on my Opensuse 13.1 x86_64 for a couple of days now and running into some issues all the time: 
I could not install pyFFTW for the first time due to some missing libraries of fftw. I found that it would be the best to install fftw from source, what I then did.

This solves the problem of a missing library but a different problem arises, when I try to either build pyFFTW from source or by using pip for the installation:

```
/usr/local/lib64/libfftw3.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

I found some people with a similar problem, but not a real solution for this. I found a hint in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162574/ld-could-not-read-symbols-bad-value-after-sabayon-package-upgrade) thread, but I could not figure out, where in the installation process I could change the compiler flag. Furthermore I found in the logs of the fftw configuring process:

```
checking for gfortran option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gfortran PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I tried the to use --enable-shared and enable  as configure flags an

```
/ ... /x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3f 
/ ... /x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3l 
/ ... /x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3_threads 
/ ... /x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3f_threads 
/ ... /x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3l_threads
```

I then did some research and found, that ./configure can have a --enable-float flag, which reduced the error message to:

```
/ ... /x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3l
/ ... /x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3_threads
/ ... /x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3l_threads
```

Since the suffix l seems to stand for long-double I found, that I could use --enable-long-double. But now I am stuck with:

```
/ ... /x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3_threads
```

My current ./configure looks is this:

```
./configure --enable-long-double --enable-threads --enable-openmp --enable-shared
```

Anybody knows, how to get this library in place?

Comment: try compiling a shared library of fftw3, add --enable-shared to the configure call, that should avoid PIC issues. Also don't forget to add --enable-sse2 (or --enable-avx) to get decent performance

Comment: Now I get
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3f
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3l
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3_threads
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3f_threads
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3l_threads
while installing pyfftw via pip... :-/

Comment: build with --enable-threads to add the thread library, also you apparently need all variants which can be built by using --enable-single and --enable-long-double. You have to configure, build and install three times.

Answer (score 2):

You have to download basic FFTW package from [here](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) and build this 3 times as follows:

```
$ cd ~/bin/fftw-3.3.5
```

or other directory you chose to unpack archive,

```
$ ./configure --enable-threads --enable-shared
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ ./configure --enable-threads --enable-shared --enable-float
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ ./configure --enable-threads --enable-shared --enable-long-double 
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The source: https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/70

Answer (score 0):

And I can add a detail about how to invoke pip install [OS X 10.9.5]: it should read something like this, in order to find all 3 installations of FFTW.

```
rollett$ sudo CPATH=/Users/Shared/fftw334single/include/
LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Shared/fftw334single/lib/:/Users/Shared/fftw334/lib/:/Users/Shared/fftw334long/lib/ 
pip install pyFFTW
```